# How to check resource access rights via team membership in firebase security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

A user should be allowed to access a resource if they are in a team that is allowed to access the resource.

How can I do this in security rules ?

I have collections:

*teams*, with a .members field in each

*resources*, with a teamsThatCanAccess for each

If i wrote this in js, itd be something like:

```
canUserAccess = (userId, resource) => {
  teams = resource.teamsThatCanAccess
  hasAccess = false
  teams.forEach((team) => {
    if (userId in team.members) {
      hasAccess = true
    }
  }
  return hasAccess
}
```

However, as I understand it, security rules dont like loops.

**--EDIT--**

To illustrate further, the database I'm building will look like something like this:

```
teams = [
  { name: "teamA", org: "org1", members: ["uid1", "uid2", "uid3"] },
  { name: "teamB", org: "org1", members: ["uid1", "uid2"] },
  { name: "teamC", org: "org1", members: ["uid3", "uid4", "uid5"] },
  { name: "teamD", org: "org2", members: ["uid201", "uid202"] },
]

resources = [
  {
    id: "projectId1",
    name: "project 1",
    org: "org1",
    teamsThatCanAccess: ["teamA", "teamB"],
  },
  {
    id: "projectId2",
    name: "project 2",
    org: "org1",
    teamsThatCanAccess: ["teamA", "teamB", "teamC"],
  },
  {
    id: "projectId3",
    name: "project 3",
    org: "org1",
    teamsThatCanAccess: ["teamC"],
  },
  {
    id: "projectId4",
    name: "project 201",
    org: "org2",
    teamsThatCanAccess: ["teamD"],
  },
]

projectFiles = [
  { content: "document text", project: "projectId1" },
  { content: "document text 2", project: "projectId1" },
  { content: "document text 3", project: "projectId2" },
]
```

Comment: It would probably be easier if you show some actual document contents so we can better understand what you're working with and how the data relates to each other.

Comment: I added now an example

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you described, you have a structure that looks like this:

```json
// document at /teams/someTeamId
{
  "members": [
    "uid1",
    "uid2",
    "uid3"
  ],
  /* ... */
}

// document at /resources/someResourceId
{
  "teamsThatCanAccess": [
    "someTeamId",
    "otherTeamId"
  ],
  /* ... */
}
```

To secure the data, you will need to introduce a new collection of documents, called something like `teamsByUser`:

```json
// document at /teamsByUser/uid1
{
  "memberOf": [
    "someTeamId",
    "otherTeamId"
  ]
}
```

By introducing this array, you can now use the [`rules.List#hasAny`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasAny) method to find if there is any overlap between the `memberOf` array in `/teamsByUser/{userId}` and the `teamsThatCanAccess` array in `/resources/{resourceId}`.

This will then allow you to configure your rules as

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /resources/{resourceId} {
      allow read: if resource.data.size() == 0 // is empty?
                  || get(/databases/$(database)/documents/teamsByUser/$(request.auth.uid)).data.memberOf.hasAny(resource.data.teamsThatCanAccess); // accessing user is a member of an allowed team
    }

    // don't forget to add rules to prevent users joining arbitrary teams from clients
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume this would require me to write something (a cloud function, perhaps) that then keeps `teamsByUser` in sync with the `teams` collection?

Comment: @ppt While you could use that approach, you can also use security rules to ensure they are synchronized. Then you just need to use batched writes to update both documents at the same time.